# Android Java Static Generic Call

Tags: java, android, generics, robolectric

I'm working with Robolectric, and in the [Robolectric class](https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/Robolectric.java) there is a static method:

```
public static <P, R> P shadowOf_(R instance) {
    return (P) ShadowWrangler.getInstance().shadowOf(instance);
}
```

I've come from a long time C# Generics background so I could be thinking of this incorrectly. My first instinct was to utilize this as such:

```
Robolectric.shadowOf_<MyShadow>(myInstance).foo();
```

However, this does not compile (plus, to me and my C# generics background, it doesnt look right).

How can I use this method?

[Source of the method is located here.](https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/Robolectric.java#L502)

Comment: could you provide the compile error?

Comment: What was the compiler message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
Robolectric.<MyShadow,X>shadowOf_(myInstance).foo();
```

where `X` is whatever the type of `myInstance` is.

Answer (score 0):

compiler can't infer what P is. Suppose P should be A here, you can

```
A a = Robolectric.shadowOf_(myInstance); // compiler can infer P=A here
a.foo();
```